# Slim 4 monolog does not write logs

Tags: monolog, slim-4

I configured `monolog` in my slim 4 application and set `logErrors` and `logErrorDetails` to true in `ErrorMIddleware` but when I got an error it does not write logs. To emulate error I turn on the cache on my app and I'm getting an error like this `Call to undefined function apcu_fetch()` b-z `doctrine` using apcu by default to cache all metadata and apcu is not installed on my dev env.

Here is the `PHP-DI` config for logger:

```
           LoggerInterface::class => static function (Container $container) {
                $config = $container->get(Config::class);
                $logger = new Logger((string)$config->get('logger.name'));

                $fileNameSuffix = PHP_SAPI === 'cli' ? 'php-cli-' : 'php-fpm';
                $logger->pushHandler(
                    new StreamHandler(
                        $config->get('logger.log_dir') . '/' . $fileNameSuffix . '-' .    $config->get('logger.name') . '.log',
                        $config->get('logger.log_level'))
                );

                if ((bool)$config->get('main.debug')) {
                    $logger->pushHandler(new FirePHPHandler());
                }

                return $logger;
            }
```

and here is the the `ErrorMiddleware` config:

```
     $definitions[ErrorMiddleware::class] = static function(ContainerInterface $container): ErrorMiddleware {

        $middleware = new ErrorMiddleware(
            $container->get(CallableResolverInterface::class),
            $container->get(ResponseFactoryInterface::class),
            (bool)$container->get(Config::class)->get('main.debug'), //false or true
            $container->has(LoggerInterface::class) ? true : false,
            $container->has(LoggerInterface::class) ? true : false
        );
        $middleware->setErrorHandler(HttpNotFoundException::class, $container->get(NotFoundHandler::class));


        return $middleware;
    };
```

And yes, I'm adding that middleware to the `App` like this `$app->add($container->get(ErrorMiddleware::class));`

I check different slim 4 skeleton Github repositories and I did not find any extra configurations, so I do not know why it's not writing the logs to the files. Maybe I need to set a custom default error handler? As slim 4 default one using php `error_log` function to write the logs?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it configure the `LoggerInterface` in my `dependencies.php`. I use [bzikarsky/gelf-php](https://github.com/bzikarsky/gelf-php) package to send the correct [GELF](https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.2/pages/gelf.html) format.

For local environment the `StreamHandler`, for any other environment the `GelfHandler` is used.

When using Graylog keep an eye on the exact port and protocol. In my example I use the `UdpTransport`. Feel free to use some other transport like `TcpTransport`.

**dependencies.php**

```php
<?php
use Monolog\Logger;

// ...
LoggerInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
    $config = $c->get(Configuration::class)->getArray('logger');
    $logger = new Logger($config['name']);

    if ($c->get(Configuration::class)->getString('settings.environment') === 'local') {
        $processor = new UidProcessor();
        $logger->pushProcessor($processor);

        $handler = new StreamHandler($config['path'], $config['level']);
    } else {
        $transport = new UdpTransport(
            $config['graylog']['host'],
            $config['graylog']['port'],
            UdpTransport::CHUNK_SIZE_LAN
        );

        $publisher = new Publisher();
        $publisher->addTransport($transport);
        $handler = new GelfHandler($publisher);
    }
    $logger->pushHandler($handler);

    return $logger;
},
// ...
```